# Tic-Tac-Toe game weird symbol

Tags: c++

I'm doing now a TTT game. but whenever I try to print the board I get something like this: https://gyazo.com/b080017e24acd68972ab4913e9cd2548

My question is what are those weird symbols and how to get rid of them

```
void TicTacToeGame::printBoard()
{
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "|1 2 3| \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "------\n";
        cout << i+1 << "|" << board[i][0] << "|" << board[i][1] << "|" << board[i][2] << "|\n";
    }
    cout << "------\n";
}
```

edit:
I init here:

```
void TicTacToeGame::playGame()
{
    char player1 = 'X';
    char player2 = 'O';
    char currentPlayer = 'X';

    bool isDone = false;

    int x, y;

    while (isDone == false)
    {
        printBoard();

        x = getXCoord();
        y = getYCoord();

        if (placeMarker(x, y, currentPlayer) == false)
        {
            cout << "can't place it here!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            changePlayers(currentPlayer, player1, player2);
        }
    }
}
```

edit2:

Has been fixed thank you for the help!

Comment: how board is declared?

Comment: Looks like your forgot to initialize your board.

Comment: You need to give more context about your code

Comment: Microsoft debug runtime fills the stack with 0xCC and this is the symbol being printed.

Comment: You need to show the code that declares the board it and fills it with spaces. I don't see any declaration of the board in playGame().

Comment: I expect `board` is a member of your class `TicTacToeGame` declared as `char board[3][3]` but you didn't fill it with spaces in your constructor.

Comment: Please do not post output on third-party websites.  If the link should break, it becomes unhelpful to other users in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those 'weird symbols' are unicode characters. After declaring your board, the char values are just random symbols, what else should the `board` elements contain?

You have to initialize your board like this:
Either on declaration:

```
char board[3][3] = {
    {' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' '}
};
```

Or in the constructor/some initialization method:

```
board = {
    {' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' '}
};
```

Now your board should consist of spaces only.